# Call controller from another controller

Tags: angularjs, devexpress

I'm not sure if the title for my question is correct, but basically what I'm trying to do is this:

I need to make a modal that contains a form. It should take in a customer id and fetch data from the server and render it in the form. This same modal can be opened from several different pages and multiple times on each page with different customer ids.

I'm using DevExpress Web so bootstrap and $uimodal and $uibmodal are not options here.

My challenge is that I dont know how to create the modal in a way that it has its own view and controller, and still be able to use it in another controller and call a method to open it or pass it a customer id to fetch from the server.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

The best I've been able to do is to bind a modal to it and watch for when it changes, but not making a method that can be called from the parent controller, but it just doesn't feel right.

Thank you in advance
Sina

Comment: How about [ngDialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog)? It allows you to create a model with its own controller and other things.

Comment: Thanks Jahongir, but ngDialog has its own modal mechanism, I'm using devexpress popup so using another dialog won't work. My question would also apply to a subview that is not a modal, but we want it to fetch and show data based on an id passed to it.